# Do multiprocessing pipes fill up, and if so what behavior do they cause in a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a threaded Python program and am using pipes, but found that they freeze at a certain point (what I would consider a relatively small amount of data). I have a test case below. I've tried digging into documentation but have been unable to find anything.

```py
import multiprocessing
def test():
   out_, in_ = multiprocessing.Pipe()
   for i in range(10**6):
      print(i)
      in_.send(i)
```

When I run this code, it prints to 278 then stops, which seems to be a small amount of data. Is this due to it running out of memory or something else? Are there any workarounds or parameters I could use to increase the size?

Comment: I run your code. It returns a range number from `0` to `1408`.

Comment: I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04, what are you running it on?

Comment: My config: Win10 Pro, Core i3, 8Go Ram.

Comment: It appears to be dependent on [`multiprocessing.connection.BUFSIZE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929502/4739755) (as well as the system it's running on)

Comment: Thanks, that BUFSIZE answer helped me figure out how to increase the size of pipes. For anyone else wondering, this link should provide the info you need: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353735

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pipes have a limited amount of storage, the amount depends on the operating system. If a process tries to write to the pipe faster than another process reads from it, the pipe will eventually fill up. When that happens, the next attempt to write will block until the reader reads enough to make space for it.

The pipe can also be put into non-blocking mode. In this case, trying to write to a full pipe will return an error indication, and the writing code can decide how to deal with it. It doesn't appear that the Python `multiprocessing` module has a way to set a pipe to non-blocking. [Python multiprocess non-blocking intercommunication using Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031613/python-multiprocess-non-blocking-intercommunication-using-pipes) says that the way to do this kind of processing is to use `in_.poll()` to tell whether the pipe is writable.